# Print query in while loop, print some fields once, print some field many times

Tags: php

I wonder how i should do if i wanna print my $sta and $stb once, but print my $test aslong as i find them in database, $sta and $stb is unique key, but there is many $test in every sta and stb

```
   <?php
    //Establish connection to database
    $host = "*****";
    $conn = *******;
    $query = " Select * 
    from p100f 
    LEfT OUTER JOIN ***** test    ****
    where p100sta = 1 AND p100stb = 1



//Execute query
$queryexe = db2_exec($conn, $query) ;
//Fetch results


while(db2_fetch_row($queryexe)) {

 $sta = db2_result($queryexe, 'p100sta');
 $stb = db2_result($queryexe, 'p100stb');
 $test = ****test******

   print("<div class='text-center'>
    <h2>$sta and $stb</h2>      <---------- this one i want to only print once
    $test       <------------------- this one i want it to repeat aslong
 as i find them in database
</div>");
```

Now when i have both in while loop its printing like this.

```
    $sta
    $stb
    $test

    $sta
    $stb
    $test

    $sta
    $stb
    $test

    $sta
    $stb
    $test
```

but i want it to print like this

```
    $sta
    $stb
    $test
    $test
    $test
    $test
    $test
```

any suggetions? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this code


//Execute query
$queryexe = db2_exec($conn, $query) ;
//Fetch results

$i=0;
while(db2_fetch_row($queryexe)) {

 $sta = db2_result($queryexe, 'p100sta');
 $stb = db2_result($queryexe, 'p100stb');
 $test = ****test******

   print("<div class='text-center'>

   if($i==0)
    {
        <h2>$sta and $stb</h2>      <---------- this one i want to only print once
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
    $test       <------------------- this one i want it to repeat aslong
 as i find them in database
</div>");  
$i++;
}//while closed
```

Comment: somehow its still looping and writing like it did before

Comment: btw. you forgot a $ sign at    if(i==0) ?

Comment: ohh yes @moe. i forgot $ before i. i have changed it.

Comment: what is the diffrence between contineu; or write $test in the else?

Comment: before while loop started with $i=0 and come in loop then 0 and print your only once value and after $i increment then 1 . second time come in loop the $i value is 1 or greater then skip and not print your only once value.continue means one type of skip your value. $test is write in outside if else condition.